# Implementing .Net OpenId with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

The sample I downloaded from [DotNetOpenId](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) has different files than the MVC 1.0 application I get when I create a new application.

I am new to MVC and openId, all the examples I have come across are very old.

Can anyone point me to examples of implementing Openid with ASP.net MVC using DotNetOpenId.

Comment: If you're still working with OpenId and MVC, do you have any updated info for this, a year later?  MVC is about to go 3.0 and I wouldn't be surprised if tool support has improved since this question was asked.

Comment: Drew, I do not have any updated info on this, I have shelved the OpenId implementation for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rob Conery has a template available for MVC that has DotNetOpenId already configured and ready to go.  Available at: 
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/putting-the-ldquo-m-rdquo-back-in-mvc/

Comment: Nerddinner uses OpenId now too. You can check out how they did it.