# Is the [Authorize] attribute for ASP.NET MVC controllers only for Membership Providers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorize, asp.net-membership

Does the [Authorize] attribute used with ASP.NET MVC controllers only function with sites that have implemented a MembershipProvider?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer is no. It just checks that there is a IPrincipal, how that gets there is up to you.

I have my own login logic that I use instead of the Membership provider, once I've authenticated a user I just call the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method. Once you've done that you can then use the [Authenticate] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The `[Authorize]` attribute is an action filter. It's going to grab the `IPrincipal` and check if the user is authenticated or if you specify roles and/or users in with the attribute, it will match against those.

There are many ways that a web request can be authenticated. Everything from Open ID to Windows Authentication. Check out this question for an OpenID example and more links to implementing authentication that way: [StackOverflow Question 961468](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961468/implementing-net-openid-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it does yes.  I imagine you could role your own and implement a similar way of doing authentication/authorization.